# Weird running times when splitting array with copyOfRange

Tags: java, arrays, split

I got a comma separated file with 10 977 120 random numbers (60 MBs), of which I have get the sum of. The task is about doing this concurrently, and thus in the fasted way possible. Long story short, I load the text file into a string array. My next idea was to then separate this array into four smaller pieces, and then for each piece, have a thread that sums the piece.

Weirdly I'm getting very different running times, when I split the list into 4 pieces.

I've got a method that looks like this:

```
public void splitNumbers(String[] numbers){
    int size = numbers.length;
    String[][] numberssplit = new String[4][];
    numberssplit[0] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 0, size/4);
    numberssplit[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (size/4)+1, size/2);
    numberssplit[2] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (size/2)+1, 3*(size/4));
    numberssplit[3] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (3*(size/4))+1, size-1);
    //MS: 2750
}
```

Above takes about 2750 ms

```
numberssplit[0] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 0, size/4);
numberssplit[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (size/4)+1, size/2);
//numberssplit[2] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (size/2)+1, 3*(size/4));
//numberssplit[3] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (3*(size/4))+1, size-1);
MS: 5
```

however, only splitting two parts, takes 5 MS, making it look like it's the last two pieces that's taking longer.

Only splitting the third part takes 2 ms

```
//numberssplit[0] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 0, size/4);
//numberssplit[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (size/4)+1, size/2);
numberssplit[2] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (size/2)+1, 3*(size/4));
//numberssplit[3] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (3*(size/4))+1, size-1);
//MS: 2
```

And so does the fourth part when it's the only piece being split.

```
//numberssplit[0] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 0, size/4);
//numberssplit[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (size/4)+1, size/2);
//numberssplit[2] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (size/2)+1, 3*(size/4));
numberssplit[3] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (3*(size/4))+1, size-1);
//MS: 2
```

At last, the last two uncommented, takes 2927 ms

```
//numberssplit[0] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 0, size/4);
//numberssplit[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (size/4)+1, size/2);
numberssplit[2] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (size/2)+1, 3*(size/4));
numberssplit[3] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (3*(size/4))+1, size-1);
//MS: 2927
```

It seems like when `numbersplit[2]` and `numbersplit[3]` is combined it takes a lot longer, but why is that? Obviously java, is doing some magic behind the scenes, but I'm unable to see the logic. So whats happening?

Comment: How many String objects are in your 60MB file? Basically, how long is your numbers array? How much memory is allocated to your jvm?

Comment: 10 977 120 numbers ^^ and I'm uncertain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer: run your project with -verbose:gc and the output will give you a full answer.**

Long answer:

I've made a test using the first block of your code.
First of all you will loose one number in those ranges:

```
(size/4)+1, size/2
(size/2)+1, 3*(size/4)
```

and two numbers here:

```
(3*(size/4))+1, size-1
```

Explanation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int)):

> from - the initial index of the range to be copied, inclusive 
>   to - the final index of the range to be copied, exclusive

As a complexity of Array.copyOfRange is (O(n)) you should not have any time difference between those four parts.
But if you see something like this that means a memory issue caused by a memory allocation.

Take a look at this:

```
package testproject;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] numbers = getNumbers(0, 10000000);

        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Starting split");
        String[][] splitted = splitNumbers(numbers);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp);

        timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Starting split");
        splitted = splitNumbers(numbers);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp);
    }

    public static String[] getNumbers(int from, int to){
        String[] res = new String[to-from];
        for(int i=0; i<(to-from); i++){
            res[i] = Integer.toString(from + i);
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static String[][] splitNumbers(String[] numbers){
        int size = numbers.length;
        String[][] numberssplit = new String[4][];
        numberssplit[0] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 0, size/4);
        numberssplit[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (size/4), size/2);
        numberssplit[2] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (size/2), 3*(size/4));
        numberssplit[3] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, (3*(size/4)), size);
        return numberssplit;
    }
}
```

Here we have calls to splitNumbers twice.

Results on my PC:

```
    Starting split
    15
    Starting split
    [GC (Allocation Failure)  626829K->625997K(764928K), 0.2908820 secs]
    [Full GC (Ergonomics)  625997K->625210K(1039872K), 3.2126996 secs]
    3510
```

So yes, as you see here we have hidden calls to garbage collector.
They cause your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider approaches that do not require copying the data.

For example, give each task the original array, but a range on which to work.

Another approach would be to represent as a List and use the [subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) method, which returns a view, not a copy.

Comment: I agree, a better idea would probably be to split this directly when reading the file, however, I'm still looking for an answer as to why above is happening, with copyOfRange, it's my curiosity :)

Comment: As I hint at in my comment above, my guess is your problem is related to memory management within the jvm. copyOfRange is a native call to copy the pointers within the array to another array. I am guessing these arrays are rather large, which requires allocating large contiguous blocks of memory. Depending on current state of memory, this can require a lot of work.

Comment: That makes sense ^^, however this just seems weird when the first two splits take 4-5 ms and the last two don't, when they are roughly the same size.